# Start a background process from a script and manage it when the script ends

Tags: shell-script, command-line, signals, background-process, job-control

I'd like to run and configure a process similarly to a  daemon from a script.
My shell is zsh emulated under Cygwin and  the daemon is [SFK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife), a basic FTP server.

For what matters here, the script `startserv.sh` can be drafted as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -s -p "Enter Password: " pw
user=testuser
share=/fshare
cmd="sfk ftpserv -user=$user -pw=$pw -usedir $share=$share"
$cmd &
```

After running the script `startserv.sh`, it stops (ends?)  without showing any prompt, then:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ends both the script and the background job process;
- Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> the script ends the process remains in the background.

Anyway I can see it only via `ps` and not `jobs`, so, when I want to close the process, I have to send a brutal `kill -9` signal, which is something I'd like to avoid in favour of  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

An alternative   *would be* running the whole script in background. 'Would be', but the `read` command is unable get the user input if the script is run as `startserv.sh &`.

Note that I need an ephemeral server, not a  true *daemon*: that is, I want the server process to run in the background, after the script ends, to perform simple interactive shell tasks (with a virtual machine guest), but  I don't need the process to survive the shell; therefore `nohup` seems not appropriate.

Comment: get the process id of the process running in the background using `bgproc="$!"` and then `command "$bgproc"`  to take the appropriate action. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process

Comment: you can also make a PID file. Then read that file to see what process number it is and go from there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> the script ends the process remains in the background.

Almost! Actually, the script has already exited by the time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, that's how you can get your prompt back (because your shell prints its `$PS1` all over again).

The reason why hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> terminates both of them is because the two of them are linked. When you execute your script, your shell initiates a subshell in which to run it. When you terminate this subshell, your background process dies, probably from a `SIGHUP` signal.

#### Separate the script, the background process and the subshell

Using `nohup`, you might be able to get rid of this little inconvenience.

```
#!/bin/sh
read -s -p "Enter Password: " pw
user=testuser
share=/fshare
cmd="sfk ftpserv -user=$user -pw=$pw -usedir $share=$share"
nohup $cmd &
```

#### The `disown` alternative

If you can switch from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`, you can give a try to `disown` as well. To know more, just type `help disown` in a `bash` instance.

```
disown -h $cmd &
```

#### Killing the background process "nicely"

Now, when it comes to killing your process, you can perfectly do a "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>" using `kill`. Just don't send a brutal `SIGKILL`. Instead, you could use:

```
$ kill -2 [PID]
$ kill -15 [PID]
```

Which will send a nice `SIGINT` (2) or `SIGTERM` (15) to your process. You may also want to print the PID value after starting the process:

```
...
nohup $cmd &
echo $!
```

... or even better, make the script wait for a `SIGINT`, and send it back to the background process *(this will keep your script in the foreground though)*:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -s -p "Enter Password: " pw
user=testuser
share=/fshare
cmd="sfk ftpserv -user=$user -pw=$pw -usedir $share=$share"
nohup $cmd &

# Storing the background process' PID.
bg_pid=$!

# Trapping SIGINTs so we can send them back to $bg_pid.
trap "kill -2 $bg_pid" 2

# In the meantime, wait for $bg_pid to end.
wait $bg_pid
```

If a `SIGINT` isn't enough, just use a `SIGTERM` instead (15) :

```
trap "kill -15 $bg_pid" 2 15
```

This way, when your script receives a `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, `kill -2`) or a `SIGTERM` while `wait`ing for the background process, it'll just relay the signals to it. If these signals do kill the `sfk` instance, then the `wait` call will return, therefore terminating your script as well :)

Comment: +1 Very informative. 
Since the script runs in a subshell, is there any possibility of accessing from the script to the job  table of the script's parent shell? That is list jobs issuing `jobs` in the terminal after the script ends (instead of `ps`).

Comment: Jobs are associated to your current shell, they are not transmitted from one shell to another. When your subshell dies, its jobs are not recovered. By printing your background process' PID, you make sure you can get information about it easily even after the subshell has terminated (`pid -p`).

Comment: nice explanation, however if your script contains more commands, they never get executed (because of the `wait`). If you remove the wait, then the signal handling is broken :/