# Start a service and Run/load a script with ssh or autossh, remote port forwarding in the background "-f" to execute more/next commands in the script!

Tags: bash, ssh, services, openssh, autossh

My config:

`debian 10.9`

`4.19.0-19-amd64`

`OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019`

`autossh 1.4g`

`GNU bash, 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

I start a service in `/etc/systemd/system/myshh.service`

`ExecStart=/home/user/ssh_run` starts my script `ssh_run`

**THIS ARE ONLY TWO OF A LOT EXAMPLES WITH SSH AND AUTOSSH I TRIED**

**ssh_run** script

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -f -NT -o "ServerAliveInteval=30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax=2" \
-R 5555:localhost:443 -l [USER] [IP] -p [PORT] -i [KEY-WITHOUT-PASSWORD]

EXECUTE NEXT COMMAND
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/autossh -f -NT -o "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes" \
-R 5555:localhost:443 -l [USER] [IP] -p [PORT] -i [KEY-WITHOUT-PASSWORD]

EXECUTE NEXT COMMAND
```

1. When i execute the command alone from the shell it works `ssh -f -NT ......`
2. When i execute only the script it works `./ssh_run`
3. When i start the service `/etc/systemd/system/myshh.service` without `-f` it works

**ALL 3 WITHOUT EXECUTE OF THE NEXT COMMANDS**

**PROBLEM:**

When i start the service `/etc/systemd/system/myshh.service`, with the script `./ssh_run` and i use `-f` for the background, now the next commands execute but, service exited with status code 0 but no ssh or autossh in `ps aux | grep [s]sh` or `ps aux | grep [a]utossh`

Checked `systemctl status myshh.service` i `grep` the `journalctl` too without an error

the service stops or restart with the same result, i try with and without `Restart=30`, `Restart=always` or `Environment="AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0"` in the service

I read most of the posts of all the stacksites, and try the search engines, no solution found
i try `(command)` , `exec`, `bash -c` .... without result...

**Now my problem/question:**

***How can i execute a ssh/autossh remote port forwarding command inside a bash script in the background, that is start from a service, to execute the next commands.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, this post save my day now:

[How do I figure out why my systemctl service didn't start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442620/515538)

Add `Type=forking` to my service file `/etc/systemd/system/myshh.service`.

**Now i can execute a ssh/autossh remote port forwarding command inside a bash script and the `-f` option for the background execution, that is start from a service, to execute the next commands/ more commands from/in a script.**

Other links to posts with relevant informations:

[How to see full log from systemctl status service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225401/how-to-see-full-log-from-systemctl-status-service)

[Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)

[Start a background process from a script and manage it when the script ends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163793/start-a-background-process-from-a-script-and-manage-it-when-the-script-ends)